# How do i obtain my smtp host?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gmail

i program a site. and i want to send a message to the user.. now in asp.net in the config file.. i put this:

```
<mailSettings>

  <smtp from="makovetskiyd@yahoo.co.uk">

    <network host="localhost" port="25" userName="username" password="secret" defaultCredentials="true" />

  </smtp>

</mailSettings>
```

i have no idea how the network host acts and what it does.. i want to change it to the server that holds my yahoo account. i understand that smtp is some email server that sends emails out.. but how do i put obtain it? how does it look like,? is it an int, is it a string?!?

```
 MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

    message.From = new MailAddress("makovetskiyd@yahoo.co.uk");



    message.To.Add(new MailAddress("makovetskiyd@yahoo.co.uk"));




    message.CC.Add(new MailAddress("makovetskiyd@yahoo.co.uk"));

    message.Subject = "This is my subject";

    message.Body = "This is the content";



    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

    client.Send(message);
```

config file:

```
    <mailSettings>

  <smtp from="makovetskiyd@yahoo.co.uk">

    <network host="smtp.yahoo.com" port="25" userName="username" password="secret" defaultCredentials="true" />// where do i get the host?!? the host prevents me from sending an email

  </smtp>

</mailSettings>
```

Comment: That depends on what smtp server you want to use... if it's your ISP's smtp server you want to use, you can ask your isp (or search on their website). The same goes for yahoo or any other mail service. You have to obtain the right smtp server from them (ie. their support website).

Comment: Also: This is off topic for Stack Overflow. SuperUser or WebApps might be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at Yahoo! Mail help pages for settings for their SMTP server. It looks like you need to be a Yahoo! Mail Plus account holder to access POP and SMTP servers however. Maybe you can use another mail account - your web hosting provider's SMTP server would be the best one to use. Read your web host's help pages.

Answer (score 1):

Network host is the address of the physical server (SMTP server) that will handle the sending of email. It could be in a form of IP address or a domain name (e.g. mail.mydomain.com). If you are working on a company they should provide this to you,

Answer (score -3):

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Net.Configuration;

Configuration configurationFile = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("PathToConfigFile");
```

Alternative

```
configurationFile = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath)

MailSettingsSectionGroup mailSettings = configurationFile.GetSectionGroup("system.net/mailSettings") as MailSettingsSectionGroup;
```

Comment: why did you provide me with the code? i already have the code.. i want to know how to get the stmp host

Comment: if (mailSettings != null)
{
    string host = mailSettings.Smtp.Network.Host;
    string password = mailSettings.Smtp.Network.Password;
    string username = mailSettings.Smtp.Network.UserName;
}